# Creating a non-rendered wrapper component in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm wanting to create a React component that does a security check and if that passes it'll render out the children of it, if it fails then it won't render anything.

I've scaffolded out a component like so:

```
var RolesRequired = React.createClass({
    permitted: roles => ...,

    render: function () {
        if (!this.permitted(this.props.roles)) {
            return null;
        }

        return this.props.children;
    }
});
```

The usage I was planning would be like this:

```
<RolesRequired roles={['admin']}>
    <h1>Welcome to the admin</h1>
    <div>
        Admin stuff here
    </div>
</RolesRequired>
```

How would you return all the children from the `RolesRequired` component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think higher order components (HOC) are also a good candidate for this. You can basically wrap any component in HOC that defines some behaviour and decides if it should render a *wrappe*.

Nicest way to do this would be if you're using a ES2015 transpiler with some ES2016 features enabled (namely decorators):

```js
function withRoles(roles) {
  return function(Component) {
    return class ComponentWithRoles extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        // Not sure where the data to get your roles about current user?
        // from but you could potentially to that here if I'm getting your point
        // and also setup listeners
        this.state = { currentUser: 'admin' }
      }

      validateRoles() {
        // you have access to the ``roles`` variable in this scope
        // you can use it to validate them.
        return true;
      }

      render() {
        if (this.validateRoles()) {
          return <Component {...this.props} />;
          )
        } else {
          return <div>Nope...</div>;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// You can then use this on any component as a decorator
@withRoles({ showOnlyFor: [ 'admin' ] })
class AdminOnlyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div> This is secert stuff </div>
  }
}
```

I've used ES2016 features because I think it's nicer to get the point across but you can implement that with just a simple function wrapping, here's a gist by one of the React core members on the topic of HOC:
https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/ef0bf1f338a7182b6775

Comment: Yeah the concept of HOC is a nicer way to go, which is essentially what I was trying to create but without the reliance on decorators (which I'm a bit hesitant about given how "preview" the feature is)

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution:

```
var RolesRequired = React.createClass({
    permitted: roles => ...,

    render: function () {
        if (!this.permitted(this.props.roles)) {
            return null;
        }

        return <div>{this.props.children}</div>;
    }
});
```

What I'm doing is wrapping the children being returned in a `<div>` but I'm having to add an unwanted/unneeded DOM element to achieve it.

Comment: React doesn't currently support returning multiple children from a `render()`, so you need a wrapper for now.